# onerror image not displayed when image does not exist? How to solve this?

Tags: javascript

```
<img id="bannerborder" runat="server" src="#"
                            alt="#" style="width: 100%;" onerror="seterrorbannerimg(this)" />

function seterrorbannerimg(obj) {

        $(obj).attr('src', "img.png");

}
```

what if img.png does not exists. how to solve this issue and display another image.

Comment: Check what the `src` attribute contains inside your error handler …?

Comment: Or remove your onerror handler in itself.

Comment: but how to stop infinite loop and set another image?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
function seterrorbannerimg(obj) {
  obj.setAttribute('src', imglink);
}
```

It should do the trick, because 'obj' is the element it self you don't have to use jquery to query for it.

[example](https://codepen.io/shamshoum/pen/rzwxKZ)

Comment: The question asks *"What if* [the image set in the error handler] *doesn't exists"* i.e How to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: but how to stop infinite loop and set another image?

Comment: You can maybe create a global counter with a fallback image or maybe another function you'd like to write in this case. In anyway if an image fails you need to generate a link that is different than the on that failed. Of course you can also check if the source is reachable and then handle it.

Answer (score 1):

It's working :p. Try checking your jquery dependency or the image path inside 'seterrorbannerimg' function.

```js
function seterrorbannerimg(obj) {

        $(obj).attr('src', "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4Mp7KqPJcVM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAA1I/3KkGlGQDj1Q/photo.jpg?sz=48");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="bannerborder" runat="server" src="#"
                            alt="#" style="width: 100%;" onerror="seterrorbannerimg(this)" />
```